# Change color of border on file upload based on if file is selected or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the border color of the `label` border based on if a file is selected or not. I am using the following jQuery and it always runs the first if statement resulting in a red border. I'm thinking that something is wrong with my if statement but I'm not sure.

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
<label for="file" id="file_display">Select File</label>

$("#file").click(function(e) {
        if ($("#file").val().length == 0) {
            $("#file_display").css("border", "5px solid red");  
        } else {
            $("#file_display").css("border", "5px solid green");    
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to monitor the element for the change event, not for click. Click is triggered when you open the dialog, change is triggered when you close it and it has a new value.

```js
tgt.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (tgt.value !== "") {
    this.classList.add('sel');
  }
});
```

```css
#tgt {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#tgt.sel {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<input id="tgt" type="file"></input>
```

Comment: How would I apply this to the label? I want to keep a white border before its clicked also.

Answer (score 1):

because the click event was calling the function at the start when empty then the function wasn't being called again I have put it on the mouseout event, green border bit annoying, i would change them round so if there's a val then have green border and I would get rid of red one altogether

```js
$("#file").on('mouseout',function(e) {
        if ($("#file").val()) {
            $("#file_display").css("border", "5px solid red");  
        } else {
            $("#file_display").css("border", "5px solid green");    
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
<label for="file" id="file_display">Select File</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on click runs as soon as you click the button so no file has been selected. Use another listener like .blur (not a complete fix since the user has to click away for it to work).

Hope this helps